# Visual Studio Code: How change c# case statement bracket indent format style?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I am writing c# code in visual studio code and I didn't install any formatter or beautifier, so I guess "C# for Visual Studio Code (Powered by OmniSharp)" is using a default formatter (whatever that is).

I like to use brackets in case statements, however, the formatter is indenting the bracket as follows.

```
switch (name)
{
    case "Bob":
        {
            break;
        }

    case "Jim"
        {
           break;
        }
}
```

How can I change the formatter so that it doesn't indent the brackets in the case statements?

Comment: You should remove the "Indent case contents" option from the Formatting/Indentation in the Tools/Options menu. Ops thats for Visual Studio. Didn't see the "Code" after that.

Comment: That is available for C_Cpp but not for c#.